# Error on GitHub Pages - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: github, github-pages, repo

I just uploaded my project written in React with Vite to my repository on GitHub, and decided to upload it to GitHub Pages, I've done this many times, but this time instead of my page I saw a white screen, and in the console error - "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () in file main.jsx::1, what is this error and how can I solve it?

Here is the link to the repo: https://github.com/cumandor/reactPortfolio

Here is the link to the page: https://cumandor.github.io/reactPortfolio/

I googled this problem and found many solutions, for example in the json file I changed the privacy, but it did not help, also wrote that the problem in Vite

UPD: I fixed the first error, but another error replaced it - main.jsx:1 Failed to load module script: JavaScript module script was expected, but the server responded with MIME type "text/jsx". According to the HTML specification there is a strict MIME type check for module scripts.